# Unable to load the service index for source error for a CodeArtifact feed using a Dockerfile

Tags: c#, docker, nuget, aws-codeartifact

It's my first question here so let me know if I have to change something or add more information.

We’re using AWS CodeArtifact for storing our packages and when we try to build a Docker image from our Dockerfile it fails because it's unable to load the source during the restore process.

We have a web API in .Net we want to deploy using AWS Fargate. This project runs smoothly from Visual Studio 2022 using Docker but we can’t build the image from PowerShell after adding our packages from CodeArtifact.

Our approach to include the credentials in the build is to pass the NuGet.Config stored on the host using Buildkit.

This’s our Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:49151

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src 
COPY . .

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Src/Presentation/Project.API/Project.API.csproj", "Src/Presentation/Project.API/"]
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
    --mount=type=secret,id=nugetconfig \
    dotnet restore "Src/Presentation/Project.API/Project.API.csproj" \
    --configfile /run/secrets/nugetconfig

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Src/Presentation/Project.API"
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
    dotnet build "Project.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build \
    --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
    dotnet publish "Project.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish \
    --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.API.dll"]
```

Our script in PowerShell:

```
docker buildx build --secret id=nugetconfig,src=$HOME\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config -f "Src\Presentation\Project.API\Dockerfile" -t my-dotnet-image .
```

Output:

```
#14 [build 6/9] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages    --mount=type=secret,id=nugetconfig  dotnet restore "Src/Presentation/Project.API/Project.API.csproj"    
--configfile /run/secrets/nugetconfig
#14 1.175   Determining projects to restore...
#14 2.504 /src/Src/Presentation/Project.API/Project.API.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source 
https://domain-123456789012.d.codeartifact.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nuget/repository/v3/index.json.
```

What are we missing here? Once we have the Dockerfile working we want to use CDK for deploying the Docker image alongside our infrastructure.

We’re using **aws codeartifact login**  command to authenticate with the service. We work on windows with a Linux container

Comment: I'm removing the `aws-fargate` tag as you just want to deploy this to Fargate eventually once you have the build working, but that is irrelevant to the issue you are currently encountering.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I cannot get around it.
Was anyone able to get past this hurdle?